# Задать отступы в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать отступы от края `RichTextBox` до текста? Эти отступы должны быть всегда, так как текст по умолчанию находится слишком близко к краю `RichTextBox`. Пример на картинке.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Уточните: вам нужно только в своём собственном приложении сделать отступ (тогда уже приведённые ответы годятся)? Или нужно в формат RTF внести изменения, чтобы потом в любом текстовом редакторе, поддерживающем этот формат, ваш текст открывался с отступами?

Answer (score 2):

См. свойства `SelectionIndent`, `SelectionRightIndent`, `SelectionHangingIndent`.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 50;
```

Это обеспечит отступ в `50` пикселей для всего текста от левого края контрола.

Comment: Согласно вопросу - **отступы должны быть всегда**. Показаные вами свойста позволяют манипулировать выделенным текстом, но не делают паддинг всего текста дефолтным.

Comment: Если свойства нет в панели свойств, то это не означает, что оно не существует. RichTextBox имеет такое свойство, просто надо ручками прописать.     richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 50;    И влиять это будет на весь текст в контроле.

Comment: Добавьте больше информации о свойствах, дайте более развернутый ответ.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionindent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо, я сам могу погуглить. Имелось ввиду вопрос подправьте, добавьте больше информации. Отвечать в одну строчку без примеров кода - плохой тон на StackOverflow.

Comment: Пример кода я приводил:  richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 50;

Comment: Ну так добавьте его в ответ! Что вы все в комментариях пишите? ([править ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/675834/edit))

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextBox` не имеет такого свойства.

Быстрое решение может быть достигнуто путем помещения `RichTextBox` в `Panel`, которая имеет такое же свойство `BackColor`, что и `RichTextBox` (обычно `Color.White`).

Затем установите свойство `Dock` для `RichTextBox` для заполнения и задайте через свойство `Padding` контрола `Panel` необходимый отступ.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520280/5598926)

Comment: Мне больше соседний ответ понравился. В этом случае скролл `RichTextBox` будет так же с отступом.

Comment: @Sv__t два этих решения - костыли. Надо автору советовать `WPF` :)

Comment: да, тут соглашусь)

Answer (score 2):

Расширьте методы `RichTextBox`:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void SetInnerMargins(this TextBoxBase textBox, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        var rect = textBox.GetFormattingRect();

        var newRect = new Rectangle(left, top, rect.Width - left - right, rect.Height - top - bottom);
        textBox.SetFormattingRect(newRect);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public readonly int Left;
        public readonly int Top;
        public readonly int Right;
        public readonly int Bottom;

        private RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Right = right;
            Bottom = bottom;
        }

        public RECT(Rectangle r) : this(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom)
        {
        }
    }

    [DllImport(@"User32.dll", EntryPoint = @"SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessageRefRect(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, ref RECT rect);

    [DllImport(@"user32.dll", EntryPoint = @"SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, ref Rectangle lParam);

    private const int EmGetrect = 0xB2;
    private const int EmSetrect = 0xB3;

    private static void SetFormattingRect(this TextBoxBase textbox, Rectangle rect)
    {
        var rc = new RECT(rect);
        SendMessageRefRect(textbox.Handle, EmSetrect, 0, ref rc);
    }

    private static Rectangle GetFormattingRect(this TextBoxBase textbox)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle();
        SendMessage(textbox.Handle, EmGetrect, (IntPtr)0, ref rect);
        return rect;
    }
}
```

Дальше в `Form_Load` используйте добавленные методы:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int m = 24; // m - margin
    richTextBox1.SetInnerMargins(m, m, m, 0); 
}
```

Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542937/7099599